# rename multiple directories using rename

Tags: unix, rename

I have a directory with multiple subdirectories (700 or so) named as such:

```
ls
quantsSample1
quantsSample2
quantsSample3
```

I want to bulk rename the subdirectories to remove "quants" from the beginning so it says `Sample1`, `Sample2` etc.

I'm using rename, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
rename 's/quants//' *
```

Nothing changes using the above...

Any advice gratefully received. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `rename 's/quants*//' *`

Comment: Nope, sorry, doesn't work.

Comment: I just try it and it worked! Can you show me how you run this script? I leave the image in following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hoEyjBNEBUro3-H-dMhL8RRMZqVR0RKE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm in the directory that lists all the subdirectories I want to change. I literally paste the code verbatim and nothing happens! When I re-list the directories they have not been renamed.

Comment: @lecb Can you capture screen?